# Getting a QSqlError("", "", "") and query.next() returns false

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, qt, qsqlquery

Hi I am trying to create a login form and i am using SQLite and Qt. The connection to the database is successful, query.prepare() returns true as well as query.exec(). However, qry.next() always returns false no matter what I do. query.lastError() returns an error like this QSqlError("", "", ""). I tried many solutions that were advised in similar discussions, but nothing helped and I don’t understand the nature of the error and what to do about it.

```
   QString username = ui->username->text();
   QString password = ui->password->text();
   QSqlQuery query(mydb);
   QString qryString = QString("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
   query.prepare(qryString); //returns true
   query.bindValue(":username", username);
   query.bindValue(":password", password);
   query.exec(); //also ok
   if(!query.next())
   {
         qDebug() << query.lastError();
   }
   else
   {
        qDebug() << "Success!";
   }
      /* while(query.next())
       {
           QString usernameFromDB = query.value(1).toString();
           QString passwordFromDB = query.value(2).toString();
           if(usernameFromDB == username && passwordFromDB == password)
           {
               QMessageBox::information(this, "Success", "Login success");
           }
           else
           {
               QMessageBox::information(this, "Failed", "Login failed 2");
           }
       }*/
```

Comment: lastError would only return something if exec failed. You need to check it's return status.

Comment: To continue with that, if next returns false, it simply means there's no results returned by the query.

Comment: I think that means there is no match in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the query by adding query.first like this:

```
    QString username = ui->username->text();
   QString password = ui->password->text();
   QSqlQuery query(mydb);
   QString qryString = QString("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");
   query.prepare(qryString); //returns true
   query.bindValue(":username", username);
   query.bindValue(":password", password);
   query.exec(); //also ok
query.first(); //add this line
   if(!query.next())
   {
         qDebug() << query.lastError();
   }
   else
   {
        qDebug() << "Success!";
   }
      /* while(query.next())
       {
           QString usernameFromDB = query.value(1).toString();
           QString passwordFromDB = query.value(2).toString();
           if(usernameFromDB == username && passwordFromDB == password)
           {
               QMessageBox::information(this, "Success", "Login success");
           }
           else
           {
               QMessageBox::information(this, "Failed", "Login failed 2");
           }
       }*/
```